# Do I Need "node_modules" Folder on Live Server

Tags: node.js, server

This may be a silly question but I have installed node on my computer and have been running tasks for creating my sass which means I have a `node_modules` folder within my project folder and I'm wondering if I need to upload the `node_modules` folder to my live server or not?

Comment: It depends on your use-case. If you're only using `node.js` to build static files, but serve them using another web-server (i.e. `nginx`), then you don't need `node_modules` on your production server.

Comment: It's a common practice for such projects to build everything (html, styles, js, minimized pictures, etc.) into a separate folder (usually `dist`) and then ship to production servers only this folder.

Comment: So if one is on Apache server (PHP), and uses node_modules locally to generate `bundle.js` with TypeScript, I presume it's unnecessary.

Comment: ...or as OP asks, if you use Live SASS Compiler (VSCode ext) or something of sorts to build CSS from many SASS files, there is no need to upload neither `/node_modules/` nor `/build/` folder or wherever your `.sass`/`.scss` reside. Just upload you `/dist/` folder where everything is compiled and ready to be used in production.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tipically you must:

- To have installed Node.js in the server (and npm).
- You generate packaje.json in local. `npm init`. You execute this in a folder containing node_modules.
- When package.json is generated. You upload it to the server.
- When package.json is in the server, specifically in your project folder, you install all dependencies with `npm install`

Answer (score -1):

You should make sure that your server had installed node.js if you want to run node.js project on your server and you can use 'npm install' to install the modulars of the package.json.